# How can i slow down the text on click in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 collapse-group">
        <p class="collapse" id="viewdetails">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
        <p>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails">View details &raquo;</a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: its working, did you include jquery?

Comment: or check error in console.

Comment: add bootstrap js file on your page

Comment: slow down? what does that mean?

Comment: yea it works, but i want to slow down (settime for displaying on click)the text inside p tag :). Yea i am using bootstrap extension.

Comment: I think OP means "slide down".

Comment: yes, its slide down or show down.. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Slow down you can try this by using `jQuery` like that:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span4 collapse-group">
    <p>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewdetails">View details &raquo;</a>
    </p>
    <p class="collapse" id="viewdetails">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>        
</div>
</div>
```

**Your JQuery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".btn-danger").click(function(){
    $("p").slideDown(1000);
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: This enables the button to slide down slow but i was looking for <p> tag to slide slow. :) thankyou.

Comment: @sawyon: answer updated, you can change the time as per your requirement. currently 1000 using.

Comment: thankyou very much :), it works

Comment: @sawyon: my pleasure.